# Load many JQuery animations in loop, but prevent any from starting until loop stops

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, width, bar-chart

I have code in which I animate many spans such that their total width is 100% of a div. The issue is in that jQuery begins animation on each iteration of the loop which decides how long a certain span will be. For instance:

```
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) { // could be 500+
   $(spans[i]).animate({
         width: SOME_NUMBER
      }, {
         duration: ANIMATION_DURATION
      });
   }
}
```

The problem I run into is that if span 1 gets a width of, say 50%, of the total div, it will begin expanding to that width significantly before the other spans begin shrinking. What I end up with is a total width of > 100% for the majority of the animation, and a gross wrap-around of the spans since they don't all fit. This happens even if I set the animation to linear instead of easing. Once the animation is over, they all end exactly where I want them to, however.

My question is:

A) Is there a way of forcing none of the animations to start until the loop has ended, and then starting them all at the exact same time?

B) Is there some other way of making sure that the total width is never > 100% at any point in time?

Here is a fiddle demonstrating what I want it to look like, however, with hundreds of spans, it doesn't animate fast enough to look like this anymore:

https://jsfiddle.net/wu7o6z37/

Comment: Loop isn't asynchronous, so all the animation start at the same time. Might be more of performance issue or an easing issue. However, you might be better using CSS animation instead of jquery. In other words, use `transition: width .5s` in CSS and in jQuery `.css( 'width', SOME_NUMBER )`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that now

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you! If you post it as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop isn't asynchronous, so all the animation start at the same time. It is more a performance issue or an easing issue. you should use CSS animation instead of jQuery. That way, it will be much more fluid.

In other words, use `transition: width .5s` in CSS and `.css( 'width', SOME_NUMBER )`